# Why was this transaction allowed on testnet?

Tags: testnet

I'm a bit confused on how testing stuff for Bitcoin on the testnet currently works.

For example, bitcoin core 0.10 enables only 40 bytes in `OP_RETURN`, but I'm not sure if 0.10 is the latest version allowed on the testnet.

I know that there are `OP_RETURN` transactions in the testnet block chain that are up to 64 bytes, as seen in this transaction:

```
{
  "transaction_hash": "91615716a4d3c42cafc240b594d79782709c2c359bd0d5a1d30fa2ee8294bcd3",
  "hex": "37356365626362356462366363636537383565633837646134353564373332646162653661313462636362623235393338643465663163373539346232303934",
  "text": "75cebcb5db6ccce785ec87da455d732dabe6a14bccbb25938d4ef1c7594b2094",
  "receiver_addresses": [

  ],
  "sender_addresses": [
    "mmHWy49WWGFQgmeZt7wYKvWSh7Szi9XQAm"
  ]
}
```

[source](http://explorer.chain.com/transactions/91615716a4d3c42cafc240b594d79782709c2c359bd0d5a1d30fa2ee8294bcd3#!transaction-op-return)

**Is the code for the testnet differences within the most recent bitcoin github repo, or is it a separate repo I must download, compile, and point towards the testnet?**

Some clarification on how this works would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, bitcoin core 0.10 enables only 40 bytes in OP_RETURN, but I'm not sure if 0.10 is the latest version allowed on the testnet.

40 bytes in OP_RETURN has always been legal. It was just non-standard, meaning that the standard client wouldn't mine or relay those transactions, but would allow them if they were already in a block.

However, testnet disables all standardness rules.

> Is the code for the testnet differences within the most recent bitcoin github repo, or is it a separate repo I must download, compile, and point towards the testnet?

It's the same program with the -testnet switch passed at the command line. (Or in your bitcoin.conf. Either works.)

Comment: Is there somewhere I can find the differences between testnet and mainnet enumerated or listed in human-readable fashion?

Comment: @bvpx I don't know if it's human readable, but the best resource I know of is https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/00820f921d8fcaa031e561ee641c50e77a909670/src/chainparams.cpp#L30

Comment: Thanks. So the major differences are the block generation / difficulty constants (in that file) and the absence of enforcement of `isStandard`.